# Process does not exit when launched from Java

Tags: java, process

I am launching WebTorrent-CLI from within my Java application as a separate process. I am using [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) for managing the process. When WebTorrent is launched with the following command, it is supposed to exit after the file at given index (value of --select) has been downloaded.

```
"D:\downloadmanager\node\webtorrent.cmd" download "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel" --select 0 --out "D://nf/"
```

As expected, webtorrent-cli does exit after downloading 0th file when the command above is used to launch it from command line. But when I try the same from within my Java app, it completely ignores the `--select` option and continues downloading other files in the torrent.

Basically, when launched as a process from Java, webtorrent ignores all the options set (`--select`, `--out` or whatever). I should mention that there is nothing wrong with the library because recently I've tried replacing it with commons-exec and that solved nothing. Also, to make sure that the right command is passed while starting the process, I'm printing the command right before calling `executor.start()`. The command above is copied from the output retrieved from printing the command before the process starts.
This is how the process is started:

```
@Override
public synchronized void start() throws IOException {
    if (mWasDownloadStarted || mWasDownloadFinished) return;

    mExec.getCommand().listIterator().forEachRemaining(s -> {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    });

    mExec.start();
    setProcessId();

    mWasDownloadStarted = true;
    mWasDownloadStopped = false;
}
```

This is how the command is prepared:

```
private String buildCommand() {
    List <String> command = new ArrayList<>();
    command.add("\"" + mManager.mWTLocation + "\"");
    command.add("download");
    command.add("\"" + mManager.mMagnetUrl + "\"");

    if (mManager.mFileIndex >= 0) {
        command.add("--select " + mManager.mFileIndex);
    }

    if (mManager.mSaveTo != null) {
        command.add("--out \"" + mManager.mSaveTo + "\"");
    }

    mManager.mExec.command(command);

    String cmdStr = "";
    for (String s : command) {
        cmdStr = cmdStr.concat(s + " ");
    }

    return cmdStr.trim();
}
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Hi. For debugging purposes, you should edit the `webtorrent.cmd` file and add an output for the parameters received. Maybe that will give a clue. If parameters are correct, it's nothing with java but with webtorrent... (maybe a background process is started when calling `webtorrent.cmd`)

Comment: @SirFartALot  Can definitely try that...cool name btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to fix this issue.

The `/` character following the path specified as value of `--out` was causing the problem. In order to fix this, I added a line in `node_modules/webtorrent-cli/bin/cmd.js` to print the arguments passed to webtorrent:

```
console.log(process.argv)
```

With the `/`, output of this line was something like the following:

```
[ 'D:\\downloadmanager\\node\\node.exe',
  'D:\\downloadmanager\\node\\node_modules\\webtorrent-cli\\bin\\cmd.js',
  'download',
  'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel',
  '--select',
  '0',
  '--out',
  'D:\\nf"' ]
```

Note the `"` that is included in the path after `D:\\nf`. When `/` is removed from the path, the quote disappears and webtorrent behaves as expected.

I doubt that this is a bug in webtorrent. I think zt-exec (or maybe I) was doing something stupid.

Somewhat unrelated, but I think I should also mention that I had to enclose every value for each option with quotes, even the index, to get rid of other nasty errors (e.g.: `Error 87, the parameter is incorrect`)